# type onClick function for html components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Every time I try to type something like `onClick` in my component like this:

```
export interface IClearButton extends SpaceProps {
  onClick: Function;
}

export const ClearButton: React.FC<IClearButton> = ({onClick}) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>
      <SomeComponent />
    </button>
  );
};
```

I end up with an error like this:

```
Type '{ onClick: Function; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IClearButton & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IClearButton & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

Currently, I just end up saying `onClick: any` which is less than ideal. How can I either extend the intrinsic `onClick` type or force overwrite it with `Function` in my type definition?

Comment: I an not getting the same error as you: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=3&ssc=31&pln=3&pc=49#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCpAD0ljmADsYkpN0k4BJAYQBtUUAEIBXGDAiM4cAN4Vpk-sDQBrAFxwAYiMYZgkgNwUAvhSq1o8NJIDO8foNHjJG5OhgA6TTwA8vASjCYhKMAHxwALxwABQyinzKKsYAlJHhcuTSRDAiUFLR8tJwPgBGwZJw8YkRcYxKqsbhRdKF0j4A9GXOYYXJRuTGBkA

Answer (score 1):

You should use interfaces `DetailedHTMLProps` and  `InputHTMLAttributes` with generics.

```
import React, { DetailedHTMLProps, InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';

interface MyProps extends DetailedHTMLProps<
    InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
    HTMLButtonElement
  > {
    name: string;
}
```

In this case type of `onClick` will be `var onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void`.
Created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-j2dhxq?file=Hello.tsx) for you.